# appollo apple add command giving error: Ensure this field has no more than 10 characters

Tags: ios

I am using appollo to build an flutter app for iOS since I do not have an MacOS device.

I am using `appollo apple add` command to "Add access to an Apple developer account" for Appollo as described here:

https://appollo.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html#step-2-link-the-api-key-in-appollo

I specify the following command:

`appollo apple add --apple-id myusername@gmail.com --name MyName --key-id <my key id> --issuer-id <my issuer id> --private-key <path to my downloaded key file named AuthKey_XXXX.p8>`

I get an error response:

`Error: for apple_id - ['Ensure this field has no more than 10 characters.']`

Since apple requires the my apple-id to be my email and my email is more than 10 characters I do not have a choice in the matter. What can I do to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `--apple-id` option of the `appollo apple add` command expects the team id and not the apple-id of the developer as described below:

https://github.com/Appollo-CLI/Appollo/issues/12#issuecomment-1463399301